# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object' MVC cshtml method call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, signalr

I'm having some some problem calling a simple method from a cshtml file in a Mvc-Project. This is the code that is givnng me the error:

```
@{
var chatHub = new TestClass();
}
@chatHub.TestMethod();
```

It's the "@chatHub.TestMethod();" that's givning me the "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'" error.

This is TestMethod:

```
public void TestMethod()
        {
            ChatHub test = new ChatHub();
            //var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
            test.JoinGrupprum1();
        }
```

And this is Joingrupprum1:

```
public void JoinGrupprum1()
        {
            Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "Grupprum1");
        }
```

Any idea what's the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With the `@` before `@chatHub.TestMethod();` you're instructing Razor to print the result of `chatHub.TestMethod()` to the HTML. In order to print something, it calls `object.ToString()` on the result.

However, your method is `void` and thus doesn't return anything. If you don't intend anything to be printed, move it inside the braces:

```
@{
    var chatHub = new TestClass();
    chatHub.TestMethod();
}
```